# What is the timeout for Firebase Phone Auth verification code? And how to set one?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

In iOS, as per the official docs, there's no method to set a timeout duration for the phone number verification code (or even know the default one). Could some Firebaser clarify why is it so? What's the default timeout duration? If possible, how could one set it in iOS?

On the other hand, in Android, all is good: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone

Comment: When you say timeout, do you mean timeout before the code expires?

Comment: @bojeil, yes, exactly.

Comment: I want to show a countdown so that the user knows how much time he has left until the code expires

Comment: [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) takes a different approach where they show a timer before they allow the user to resend the code (they use 15 seconds). This is a better approach as even if the expiration is provided, it will be inaccurate due to various latencies in the flow and the value is likely to change as Firebase Auth has the right to change that for security reasons. Otherwise, it could be used for brute force attacks.

Comment: So, what should I do for iOS? And why does Android has the option to set a timeout duration while iOS does not?

Comment: The timeout for android is unrelated. It is the timeout for code auto retrieval before you ask the user to provide the code and not the timeout for code entry. Auto retrieval is an android feature only.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @bojeil ;)

Comment: Thanks, Rosário, I have added that as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseUI takes a different approach where they show a timer before they allow the user to resend the code (they use 15 seconds). This is a better approach as even if the expiration is provided, it will be inaccurate due to various latencies in the flow and the value is likely to change as Firebase Auth has the right to change that for security reasons. Otherwise, it could be used for brute force attacks.

The `onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut` timeout for Android is unrelated. It is the timeout for code auto retrieval before you ask the user to provide the code and not the timeout for code entry. Auto retrieval is an android feature only.

Comment: how  can we change the 15 sec timer of firebase UI?